# Selecting JavaScript Dropdown in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I'm just brushing up on my selenium and have this problem. I'm popultaing the google sign in page at https://accounts.google.com/signup. I'm trying to enter the value 'February' in the Birth Month Field. Since I cannot use the select option here, i'm clicking on it to expand, and the waiting for a while and the clicking on the xpath of the option February.

```
    //Setting up the Birthday
    w1=d1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']"));
    System.out.println(w1.getText());
    w1.click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    d1.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':2']")).click();
    d1.findElement(By.id("BirthDay")).sendKeys("17");
    d1.findElement(By.id("BirthYear")).sendKeys("1982");
```

But it does not select anything. Nor does it throw an error. It behaves as though I clicked outside the box and closed it. The page says 'you cannot leave this option blank' and my code terminates. Why could this be happening? Could this be an issue with the finder for the option February?

Comment: Have you fill all mandatory fields ?
How are you sure that the problem comes from the February option ?
At your place, remove the command which sends the form and looks well if something is missing.

Comment: No.  This field is mandatory,  but I cannot seem to fill it.

Comment: yet, you should. I wrote an answer. Try it :)